# what does "WITH THE" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **With the** North Atlantic Treaty Organization (NATO) incorporating the USA, the OSCE’s mission is evolving from being a facilitator of security dialogue and a promoter of democratization to engagement in the business of peacekeeping.
>   According to Nina Graeger and Alexandra Novosseloff, this organization ‘is the most important norm-building organization in Europe’, although this effectiveness is limited by renewed strategic rivalry between the USA and Russia.

does "with the" mean "BY USING" exactly here? is another meaning according to context?

Comment: Don't forget to provide a [link to your source](http://epubbookonline.com/b/5427/joseph-m-siracusa/diplomacy-a-very-short-introduction/9) when you are quoting material.

Comment: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

With the: "used for saying what event makes something possible"

A more common phrase meaning the same thing is 'due to': caused by or ascribable to; because of.

i.e. "Due to the North Atlantic Treaty Organisation (NATO) incorporating the USA..."

Answer (score 0):

> **Following upon the** North Atlantic Treaty Organization (NATO) incorporating the USA, the OSCE’s mission is evolving from being a facilitator of security dialogue and a promoter of democratization to engagement in the business of peacekeeping.

meaning OSCE is building on the progress/activity already completed by NATO.

See [with](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/with):

> 22) following upon; after"   ⇒ *with that remark, he left*"